# How to show that this function is differentiable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

Let $$\phi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{\mathbb{C}}, s \mapsto \int_2^{\infty} \frac{e^{isx}}{x^2\ln(x)}dx$$, I want to show that this function is differentiable everywhere. Unfortunately, it appears to me that it is impossible to use the standard dominated convergence theorem to show the differentiability, so I wanted to ask you for stronger methods?

Comment: Is not possible to bound with $|\frac{e^{isx}}{x^2\ln(x)}|\leq \frac{1}{x^2\ln(x)}$ which is integrable? Sorry I might miss something...

Comment: you need to bound the derivative for interchanging differentiation and integration

Comment: ahhh yes you are absolutely right. I just had a wrong version of the Theorem in mind. Sorry!

Comment: no problem, thanks for thinking about it ;-)

Comment: @Thorben But a simple bound of that form applied to the difference quotient does not work anyway. It is a tricky question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We expect that 
$$
\frac{d}{ds} \int_2^{\infty} \frac{e^{isx}}{x^2\ln(x)}\,dx
= i \int_2^{\infty} \frac{e^{isx}}{x\ln(x)}\,dx \tag{1}
$$
but justification is problematic because the integral on the right does not converge absolutely (i.e., it does not converge as a Lebesgue integral).

Here's an idea: integrate by parts first. 
$$
\int_2^{\infty} \frac{e^{isx}}{x^2\ln(x)}\,dx = \frac{e^{2is}}{8 is \ln(2)}  + \frac{1}{is} \int_2^{\infty} \frac{e^{isx} (2\ln x+1)}{x^3\ln^2(x)}\,dx 
\tag{2} $$ 
Now, formal differentiation  with respect to $s$ produces 
$$ \frac{d}{ds}  \int_2^{\infty} \frac{e^{isx} (2\ln x+1)}{x^3\ln^2(x)}\,dx 
= i \int_2^{\infty} \frac{e^{isx} (2\ln x+1)}{x^2\ln^2(x)}\,dx \tag{3} $$
which is absolutely convergent. So, you can use Fubini's theorem to show that integration of the right hand side in (3) with respect to $s$ indeed brings you back to the function you differentiated.

The above only shows differentiability at $s\ne 0$. Then you should consider the limit of the derivative as $s\to 0$. If it exists, mean value theorem completes the job. If it does not exist (I somehow suspect the imaginary part will blow up), then the function is not differentiable at $s=0$.